# Determine ideal interval time for running an update script

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, google-chrome-extension, setinterval

I am writing a chrome extension for a website such as facebook and quora. The website's content is dynamically updated and I need to work on the content as and when it arrives. The script I have written right now is scheduled to run every 1 second (using javascript `setInterval` function). However, this slows down the other site very noticeably.

My question is how to determine the acceptable interval time. Another side question: How do sites like Facebook determine when to update their content?

Comment: If 1 second slows things down, then try with 0.5 sec, 0.1 sec, 0.05 sec etc. There is no straight-forward answer. You will have to run some experiment and empirically determines what works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook and Quora are likely using a real-time solution like [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets).

You would need access to the stream/endpoint to get real-time data like Facebook and Quora show on their pages.

Because of this, all you can do is poll their API at a defined interval.